# Is it possible to use Ajax success result to populate jQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I would like to declare my jQuery datatable without initially populating it and later when calling Ajax functions, I would like to take the results and use that as the data source for my data table, right now I am making multiple Ajax calls for the same purpose and I would like to eliminate this if possible.

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/Receiving/GetUnorderedParts",
datatype: "html",
data: { "id": button.attr("data-ponumber") },
success: function(data) {
    var orderButton = $(".js-Order");
    orderButton.removeClass("invisible");
    tbl = $("#UnorderedDetail")
        .DataTable({
            "destroy": true,
            "searching": false,
            "ordering": false,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "paging": true,
            "lengthMenu": [10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
            ajax: {
                url: "/Receiving/GetUnorderedParts",
                data: { "id": button.attr("data-ponumber") },
                datasrc: ""
            },
            "columnDefs": [
                {
                    targets: -1,
                    className: 'dt-body-center'
                }
            ],
            columns: [
                {
                    data: "Description"
                },
                {
                    data: "VendorPartNumber"
                },
                {
                    data: "Quantity"
                },
                {
                    data: "CartID",
                    render: function(data) {
                        return "<button class='btn btn-danger js-delete' data-cart-id=" +
                            data +
                            ">Delete</button>";
                    }
                }
            ] //EOColumns
        }); //EODataTable

} //EOSuccess
```

}); //EOInnerAjax

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function to build the data table on success something like:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/Receiving/GetUnorderedParts",
datatype: "html",
data: { "id": button.attr("data-ponumber") },
success: function(data) {
    var orderButton = $(".js-Order");
    orderButton.removeClass("invisible");
    createTable(data);
}
});
```

and the function can take in the array of objects and create a data table:

```
function createTable(dataSet)
{
       $('#example').DataTable({        
        data: dataSet,
       "aoColumns": [{
                   "sTitle": "Description",
                   "mData": "Description"
                  }, {
                   "sTitle": "VendorPartNumber",
                   "mData": "VendorPartNumber"
                  }, {
                   "sTitle": "Quantity",
                   "mData": "Quantity"
                  }, {
                   "sTitle": "CartID",
                   "mData": "CartID",
                   "mRender": function(data) {
                    return "<button class='btn btn-danger js-delete' data-cart- id=" + data + ">Delete</button>";
                   }}]         
      });
}
```

[Check out a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheUnknownGuy/r9s74efy/6/) . It takes in an array of objects and create a datatable.